# Massive memory bloat when appending named tuples to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

**Quick start guide**: In python 3.5, what I expect to take roughly 5GB in memory instead takes over 15GB and then crashes due to lack of resources.

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

Hdr1 = namedtuple("Hdr1", "id hash source options elements locations")
Hdr2 = namedtuple("Hdr2", "id hash source options stream locations")
Hdr3 = namedtuple("Hdr3", "id hash source options series locations")
Identifier = namedtuple("Identifier", "id hash")
Location = namedtuple("Location", "index tell")
IndexData = namedtuple("IndexData", "filenames packet1 packet2 packet3")

filenames = [] # filled by other code, but it's a list, with 10 items
packet1_d = {}
packet2_d = {}
packet3_d = {}

index_data = IndexData(filenames, packet1_d, packet2_d, packet3_d)

# for each file
# read all the packets in the file, get the tell() location each time
if packet is header:
  if packet is packet1_header:
    packet1_d[Identifier(id, hash)] = Hdr1(id, hash, source, options, [])
  elif packet is packet2_header:
    packet2_d[Identifier(id, hash)] = Hdr2(id, hash, source, options, stream, [])
  else 
    packet3_d[Identifier(id, hash)] = Hdr3(id, hash, source, options, series, [])
else
  loc = Location(index, tell)
  # This part below is deadly
  if packet is packet1:
    packet1_d[Identifier(id, hash)].locations.append(loc)
  if packet is packet2:
    packet2_d[Identifier(id, hash)].locations.append(loc)
  if packet is packet3:
    packet3_d[Identifier(id, hash)].locations.append(loc)

pickle.dump(index_data, open("index_data.p", "wb"))
```

**Details:** This is obviously not all the code - I kept out the parts that open and parse the files, and obviously you won't have the files available, so you can't reproduce the issue.  The `is` statements are pseudo-code but logically equivalent.  This is a true representation of how I set up my data structures, so estimates of memory usage will be accurate, and it's an accurate portrayal of how my variables are used, so should be representative for finding memory leaks.

When I comment out the 6 lines that I commented as "deadly", after running through 10 GB of data and about 100M packets, the pickle file (containing only the filenames, and the lists of different packet headers) is somewhere between 5 and 10 MB.  I know pickle compresses, but that still means the "base data" is less than 50 MB.

There are 91,116,480 data packets total.  For the sake of easy calculations, lets just call that 100M.  Each `Location` is only an index into the list of files and the return from `file.tell()`.  Empirical testing in the interactive shell says each 'Location' is 64 bytes:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Location = namedtuple("Location", "idx tell")
>>> fobj = open("/really/big/data.file", "rb")
>>> fobj.seek(1000000000)
1000000000
>>> tell = fobj.tell()
>>> loc = Location(9, tell)
>>> sys.getsizeof(loc)
64
```

So the total memory usage should be no more than 6.4 GB.

Why does this take up over 15 GB of memory?  Is there a more memory-efficient way for me to set up this data?

I worked around this by putting all that data in a sqlite database file.  The entire file is 2.1GB, so it seems the raw data shouldn't be more than 2.1 GB.  I can understand the overhead in Python that would get it in the 6GB range, but it shouldn't be hitting 15 GB.  Even though I've worked around the issue, I'd like to know how to avoid it next time.

Comment: The return of `sys.getsizeof(` is the size of only the _tuple_  object - not of the contained objects. Each integer number in Python is an independent object taking about 28 bytes (64bit build) - that adds to your 64 byte. And while pickling, the process needs to keep both the native object instance, and the serialized version in memory (maybe Pikcle should not do that, since it is writing the results to a file,  but it might take note of already encoded objects to avoid circular references)

Comment: So you're saying that the tuple + the two ints is 120 bytes?  That times 100M data points would account for much of the issue right there.  In that case, the answer is to not use tuples.  It sounds like Mathias' suggestion of typed arrays would drastically reduce the memory footprint, then?

Comment: I still hold taht you  better of using sqlite  there. Otherwise, a custom class -not a named tuple, that would hold your values in 8 bytes would be nice - but you'd still have the object overhead. 1,2, o3 3 element arrays will have quite an overhead as well - since beyond the nubmers they have to hold object information.

Comment: You could use three index files, instead of just one pickled file, and write binary (struct) data direct to that file. A Python class that can work, transparently,  as a  sequence in those files is something easy to write

Comment: Sqlite seems to be a very viable solution, and will (hopefully) help when I make my processing use multiple cores.  In the end, that's what I'll stick with.  It just really helps for me to know how to avoid this memory bloat in the future.  Your idea of struct data plus a class might be worth turning into an answer - that sounds like a perfect way to (micro-)manage what's saved in memory.

Comment: Sicne I am working on an open source project were this makes sense, I will make that work - nameddtuple like objec wher eone can pre-specify the object types. It can later go into my https://github.com/jsbueno/extralist project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in the other answer, this is a case where you'd be better of keeping your data in disk, managed by a database system.

The problem you are facing is that, although compact, each field in a namedtuple - including fields that contain only numeric values, are a full Python object. And integer numbers in Python do use ~30 bytes  - that is for each field plus the namedtuple object size itself - ~64bytes.

In the standarlibrary, the `ctypes` module features a "Structure"  base type that *can* create arrays of objects records in which each record will only use the number of bytes needed for its data. That is, if you create a Structure using 1 4-byte integer and 1 8-byte integer, each record will take 12 bytes. + hundred and a few bytes for information about the array itself. 
The problem with `ctypes.Structure` arrays is that you have to create then with a fixed size - it is not possible to simply go appending more records to their end. And if you create one stand-alone Structure object for each record, you have again an overhead of ~100 bytes for each record.

Numpy, Python's de facto library for crunching big numbers, and the underlying engine for Pandas (which might be a higher solution for your problem in a higher level) allows you to create arrays with specified records, determining the byte-type for each record. But ordinary numpy arrays have the same problem of being fixed size - you can't just add arbitrary records to an array.

Pandas - http://pandas.pydata.org/ - is probably what you should be using there.

But if you aren't, I've put together a couple classes that make use of Python's stdlib "struct" to just arrrange data in memory, allowing each 12 bytes record to use just 12 bytes and nothing more - and it is pickleable.

You can use the file at https://github.com/jsbueno/extralist/blob/master/extralist/structsequence.py as it is - each "StrutureSequence" object is created more or less like a namedtuple, plus a record-structure information as documented here https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings 
In your code, just use an instance of StructSequence where you are creating lists - you can even append a (field - compatible) namedtuple object to these sequences -  they will just store the data in memory. And pickle will work just fine with them.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers the initial question of how the code got so bloaty, and gives me a (custom-built!) solution to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mostly asking for an implementation detail - it is hard to tell when  Python object will use 2Kb instead of 500b - and even if you fix the precise issue you are tracking, it would be good until your data double in size once more,

What you need there is to switch to a streaming approach - in which you read/process/write data as they are needed. This will mean chanigng the output format - it can even be a "pickle file", but instead of monolitic dictionaries, you can Pickle smaller objects (maybe even a sequence of small dictionaries that are just to be applied as "update" on top of each other on read);

But if you jut switch your output to say, a sqlite database, (in which you can even Pickle your needed objects as column data), you'd be good to go, for this data and many more)

Comment: Thanks.  I had considered breaking up the monolith into smaller bits, but then I'd have to load all of them into memory for some of the searches I'd be doing.  The database idea is working out very well for me, though.  I'll have to look into sqlalchemy; right now, sqlite seems to be doing everything I need.

Comment: Actually - it was a tpo - I was going to write just sqlite Sqlalchemy might beoverkill for this(it s not a databse - it is an ORM which affords multiple backends)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like more than what I need at this time. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 2):

Try turning the `locations` into a [typed array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) instead of a list of objects. The array is represented as an efficient C-style array in memory, so a list of N 32-bit numbers needs just N * 4 bytes of memory.

Your `Location` type has just an `index` and a `tell`, so if they're both 32-bit integers, you can use the `'i'` typecode like this (only `packet1` case shown, for brevity):

```
import array
LocationArray = namedtuple("LocationArray", "index tell")
if packet is header:
    locations = LocationArray(index=array.array('i'), tell=array.array('i'))
    packet1_d[Identifier(id, hash)] = Hdr1(id, hash, source, options, locations)
else:
    loc = packet1_d[Identifier(id, hash)].locations
    loc.index.append(index)
    loc.tell.append(tell)
```

(edited to use a namedtuple LocationArray rather than an ordinary tuple.)

Comment: I don't know how typed array fell off my radar, but I'll remember it in the future.  Almost all of my uses of list would probably be better as typed arrays.